# GMSPlacesClient give me a exception of nil URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to get details information of places by its placeID. 
I am using google map API.

```
GMSPlacesClient *tempClient = [GMSPlacesClient sharedClient];
```

When I tried to create instance of **GMSPlacesClient** the app crashes.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: nil URL argument'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are calling this method in Main Thread.

Comment: @Krupanshu  
I am calling this method in main thread only.

Comment: have you found any solution ?